# how to select data from two table and sum the balance from debit and credit columns (php)

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

credit table

```
id     date      credit
1    4-1-2019     300
2   10-1-2019     500
3   10-2-2019     300
```

debit table

```
id     date      debit
1    2-1-2019     400
2   6-1-2019     600
3   2-2-2019     300
```

I want to get a table which to merge those data and show the balance, ordered by the date

somthing like this

```
id     date      debit  credit  balance
1    2-1-2019     400            400
1    4-1-2019             300    100
2    6-1-2019     600            700
2   10-1-2019             500    200
3    2-2-2019     300            500
3   10-2-2019             300    200
```

**UPDATE**

I am using @Gordon Linoff code

```
select b.*,
   (@b := @b + coalesce(debit, 0) - coalesce(credit, 0)) as balance from (select id, date, debit, credit
  from ((select id, date, debit, "0" as credit
         from debit
        ) union all
        (select id, date, "0" as debit, credit
         from credit 
        )
       ) b
  order by date
 ) b CROSS join
 (select @b := 0) params
```

it working but i geting output like this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sINyk.png)

```
id     date      debit  credit  balance
1    2-1-2019     400            400
2    6-1-2019     600            1000
3    2-2-2019     300            1300
1    4-1-2019             300    1000
2   10-1-2019             500    500
3   10-2-2019             300    200
```

I need to sort whole data by date here as you can see first sorted data of  debit table then data of credit table

Comment: You should explain what you've tried so far, so others might find your problem faster and give you a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the tables using `union all`.  In MySQL 8+ you can calculate the last column using cumulative sums:

```
select id, date, debit, credit,
       sum( coalesce(debit, 0) - coalesce(credit, 0) ) over (order by date) as balance
from ((select id, date, debit, null as credit
       from debit
      ) union all
      (select id, date, null as debit, credit
       from credit 
      )
     ) b
order by date;
```

In earlier versions, you can use variables for the calculation:

```
select b.*,
       (@b := @b + coalesce(debit, 0) - coalesce(credit, 0)) as balance
from (select id, date, debit, credit
      from ((select id, date, debit, null as credit
             from debit
            ) union all
            (select id, date, null as debit, credit
             from credit 
            )
           ) b
      order by date
     ) b cross join
     (select @b := 0) params
order by date;
```

Comment: I do not understand something. Should not it be `@b := @b + coalesce(`?

Comment: @bato3 YES correct finally worked. thanks, both guys :) you guys make my day :)

Comment: this code sorting only one table value ie it sorting credit table date then debit table date. i need sort whole table with date wise only

Comment: @SharoonCk . . . Then just `order by date`.  It is unclear from your question what the sorting key is.  I made the change to just order by the date.

Comment: Ya i also changed as date. But it showing in a way that first debit table sorted by date  data then credit table sorted by date data.. i need data just like i mentioned qstion. Ie whole data sorted by date

Comment: @SharoonCk . . . That is what this answer does.

Comment: when i use ther showing error an unexpected token near ( balance)